# How to get PHP error reporting and logging working?

Tags: php, error-logging, error-reporting, error-log

The following code:

```
echo 'display_errors: '.ini_get('display_errors').'<br>';
echo 'log_errors: '.ini_get('log_errors').'<br>';
echo 'error_log: '.ini_get('error_log').'<br>';
echo 'error_reporting: '.ini_get('error_reporting').'<br>';

error_log('test 123');
```

produces the following output:

```
display_errors: 1
log_errors: 1
error_log: /home/sitename/public_html/error_log
error_reporting: E_ALL
```

Also 'test 123' appears in the correct error log, but when I try to produce an error using the following script:

```
<?php

  echo (12312312)
  1qweeqw

?>
```

I get nothing, but a white page. This code should display something like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/sitename/public_html/test.php on line 4
```

I does just that on another server. This is some cheap hosting with cPanel. I'm slowly going mad. Please help.

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053431/1213708 is probably the most relevant in this case as it's a parse error and not a runtime error.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all ... On other servers it was enough to set display_errors to on and error_reporting to E_ALL and everything would be fine ...